# Multiple item in PayPal HTML Form not working

Tags: paypal

I can add an item just fine with this form:

```
          <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

          <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item 1">
          <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="20">

          <input type="hidden" name="business" value="myemail@hidden.com">
          <input type="submit" name="submit">
```

However, I'd like to add multiple items. I've been struggling and reading all over. This is not working:

```
          <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">

          <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Item 1">
          <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="20">

          <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Item 2">
          <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="25">

          <input type="hidden" name="business" value="myemail@hidden.com">
          <input type="submit" name="submit">
```

Source: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem. It's not mentionned anywhere but you need this following line;

```
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
```

Hours wasted. T.T